# How to sort a custom Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparable

I am working on a custom Linked List based on Crunchify's implementation to display list of Employee. As of now I can add new Employee or remove existing Employee from the list. However, my project requires adding a sorting method that would not be based on Collections.sort(). My teacher wants this sorting method to be custom, so this is quite difficult for me. Is there anyway to sort this list by first name that is easy to code (I'm completely new to object oriented programming)?

Here is my custom Linked List:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyLinkedListTest2 {
public static MyLinkedList linkededList;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    linkededList = new MyLinkedList();


    linkededList.add(new Employee("Agness", "Bed", 2000.0, 32));
    linkededList.add(new Employee("Adriano", "Phuks", 4000.0, 16));
    linkededList.add(new Employee("Panda", "Mocs", 6000.0, 35));


    System.out.println(linkededList);

    //OPTIONS
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int selection;
        do {
            System.out.println("OPTIONS:\n[1] ADD EMPLOYEE\n[2] REMOVE EMPLOYEE\n[3] SORT \n[4] EXIT\n");

            selection = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Name:");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    String name = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Surname:");
                    String surname = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Salary:");
                    double salary = scanner.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Experience:");
                    int experience = scanner.nextInt();
                    linkededList.add(new Employee(name, surname, salary, experience));
                    System.out.println(linkededList);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Which row do you want to remove?");
                    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (choice == 0)
                        System.out.println("No such row exists");
                    else if (choice > linkededList.size())
                        System.out.println("No such row exists");
                    else
                        linkededList.remove(choice - 1);

                    System.out.println(linkededList);
                    break;  
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("SORT BY: 1.NAME\t2.SURNAME\t3.SALARY\t4.EXPERIENCE\n");
                    //In this section sorting algorithm should be added
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;  
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong choice");                 
            }
        } while (selection != 4);

  }

}

class MyLinkedList<Employee> {

private static int counter;
private Node head;

public MyLinkedList() {

}


public void add(Object data) {


    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
    }

    Node myTemp = new Node(data);
    Node myCurrent = head;


    if (myCurrent != null) {

        while (myCurrent.getNext() != null) {
            myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
        }

        myCurrent.setNext(myTemp);
    }

    incrementCounter();
}

private static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

private static void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
}

private void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
}

public void add(Object data, int index) {
    Node myTemp = new Node(data);
    Node myCurrent = head;

    if (myCurrent != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < index && myCurrent.getNext() != null; i++) {
            myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
        }
    }

    myTemp.setNext(myCurrent.getNext());

    myCurrent.setNext(myTemp);

    incrementCounter();
}

public Object get(int index){
    if (index < 0)
        return null;
    Node myCurrent = null;
    if (head != null) {
        myCurrent = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (myCurrent.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
        }
        return myCurrent.getData();
    }
    return myCurrent;

}

public boolean remove(int index) {

    if (index < 1 || index > size())
        return false;

    Node myCurrent = head;
    if (head != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (myCurrent.getNext() == null)
                return false;

            myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
        }
        myCurrent.setNext(myCurrent.getNext().getNext());

        decrementCounter();
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

public int size() {
    return getCounter();
}

public String toString() {
    String output = "";

    if (head != null) {
        Node myCurrent = head.getNext();
        while (myCurrent != null) {
            output += myCurrent.getData().toString();
            myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
        }

    }
    return output;
}
public void compare(int index){
    Node myCurrent = head.getNext();
    if(myCurrent != myCurrent.getNext())
        myCurrent = head;
    else 
        myCurrent = myCurrent.getNext();
}

private class Node {
    Node next;

    Object data;

    public Node(Object dataValue) {
        next = null;
        data = dataValue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Node(Object dataValue, Node nextValue) {
        next = nextValue;
        data = dataValue;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setData(Object dataValue) {
        data = dataValue;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node nextValue) {
        next = nextValue;
    }

 }
}
```

Also, here is my Employee class that the list is based on:

```
public class Employee
{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;
    private int experience;


    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, double salary, int experience)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public int getExperience()
    {
        return experience;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String ret = "\n" +"Name: "+firstName +" | Surname: "+lastName +" | Salary: "+salary + " | Experience: "+experience +"\n";
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The code is compiling now, but maybe you have some recommendation regarding this implementation of Linked List? I would be grateful if someone comes up with a solution for sorting, since with this my project will be completed. Only Comparable can be used, while Collections.sort() method cannot be implemented due to project's requirements.

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Questions asking for "recommendation regarding this implementation of Linked List" and asking for someone to provide code are considered off topic. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) and 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/989)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more why you can't use Collection.sort? Is it because your project want's to see how you implement a sorting algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I can. My teacher wants this sorting method to be custom, so it has to use list logic. I think Collections.sort wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own EmployeeComparator that implements `Comparator<Employee>` (see [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) and use it like following :

```
SortedSet<Employee> set = new TreeSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparator());
set.addAll(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to implement the sorting yourself, one of the easiest way could be so compare each list node with the next one and swap them if they are not in sorted order. You need to do this until there is any such out of order nodes left in the list.

You can see bubble sort implementation for an idea on how this works.

Comment: Hello, thank you for advice. I am digging bubble sort implementation right now. However, how to compare each node by Employee's first name in this case. Should I move each node to an array and then use sorting?

Comment: In the linked list you have 'Object data;' since you are storing Employee type objects here you can as well make it 'Employee data' then you will have the fields of employee accessible. You should not require another array, you need a way to swap two items in list so that if current order is A -> C -> B you can swap any two items to make it something like A -> B -> C note that the next for nodes A, B, and C changed here. You can find good examples of such code online.